# What is the meaning of this declaration: int (*packet_xmit)(struct sk_buff *skb);?

Tags: linux-kernel, network-programming

I know this might work as a skb packet transmitter, but why I cannot find packet_xmit definition in any version of the linux kernel code?

Comment: Because what you show in the title *is* the definition? Depending on context it declares or defines a *variable* named `packet_xmit`, which is a pointer to a function taking a `struct sk_buff *` argument, and returns an `int`.

Comment: A-ha, now I get it.
So, we can call it in this way, for instance: cp->packet_xmit(&skb)

Cheers

Comment: Yes, for example. Assuming there is a `cp->packet_xmit = &some_function;` somewhere before.